# Make Media Directory of a CMS available on local development, with fallback to production data (for example Magento 2 public/media)

Tags: content-management-system, magento2, media, development-environment, shopware6

When developing web shops (using Magento 2, Shopware 6, ...), we do not want to copy all media assets to the local development machine.

Still it would be nice, to get a real view on the system, i.e. load the media images on demand from the production server.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case Shopware 6 is used, this might also be an option:

https://github.com/tinect/TinectMediaStaging

If requests the missing media files from production.

In Shopware 6, also the following rewrite rule in Apache would do.

In other Shopsystem, it depends a bit if the local installation needs to access the local images (for example to determine size / resize) or just includes the fixed URL in the HTML which then could be rewritten using a similar rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shop.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thumbnail/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shop.example.com/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The beauty is, that you can still upload new pictures locally for testing, because it first checks if they are available locally.

Eventually add twice

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(dev|local)$ [NC]
```

If your dev systems end in `.dev` or `.local` so you can use this in the generic `.htaccess` without needing a modified one for the local dev.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2 there is [a open source module](https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/magento2-mediastoragesync) which does exactly this.

If you are on Linux, a more generic solution seems to be possible, using http and union fuse file systems. This could work on different Shop- and CMS systems such as Shopware, TYPO3 and so on.

The following example was tested on Ubuntu 20.04

**But: the solution is not well tested on production installations, so please be careful.**

First install the required packages

```
apt install httpdirfs unionfs-fuse
```

We assume, the production server uses Apache. In the next step we enable directory listing, but only for a certain - secret - user agent. Make sure to replace "ThisIsSecret" by your secret.

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == 'ThisIsSecret'">
  Options +Indexes +MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
</If>
<Else>
  Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Else>
```

Go to your local development directory and move the current `media` directory:

```
cd /home/me/projects/example.com/public
mv media media_local
```

Now `httpdirfs` is used to mount the server's directory via HTTP. `httpdirfs` parses the directory listing and lets you see the remote files. Editing is not possible.

```
mkdir media_remote
httpdirfs --cache --user-agent ThisIsSecret https://example.com/media/ media_remote
```

Next, we use `unionfs` with the CopyOnWrite (`cow`) option to be able to still write to the media folder.

```
mkdir media
unionfs-fuse -o cow media_local=RW:media_remote=RO media
```