# How to manage media on Shopware 6 development systems? To commit to git or not to commit?

Tags: git, media, shopware

We are using Git to develop Shopware (6.3.5.2) shops for customers. We have plenty of test instances on Magento we keep media used for the general page structure (such as logos) i.e. wysiwyg folder in the git LFS. We do not keep product images (magento/pub/media/catalog) in the GIT an so the placeholders are used.

Is there a way to commit only general images to the GIT in Shopware? The difference is here, that all images are kept in hashed folders like `public/media/0f/67` ...

We could just identify the media we need by going through that folder and commit (`git commit -f`) it from there, ignoring everyhing else.

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

We [also tried to come up with a solution which avoid having any media in the GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65869308/288568), but it's not yet working well.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to handle such media is to store them in your theme or plugin in the directory `yourtheme/src/Resources/public`, e.g. `yourtheme/src/Resources/public/assets/images/image.jpg`. You commit all the assets to git.

To include your assets in your templates use the Twig function [asset](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#linking-to-css-javascript-and-image-assets), e.g.:

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/yourtheme/assets/images/image.jpg') }}">
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/developer-guide/storefront/assets#using-custom-assets) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer. The downsite is that it causes additional effort where the standard theme is normally configurable via the admin panel and stores in media. This comfort is lost then :-)

Comment: @Alex well, IMHO if you want the comfort of having configurable theme media in the admin, then there is no point to commit these media to git anyway. But when it comes to logos, I suppose you can define them in your theme.json file just like in [the default theme](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Resources/theme.json), but I never tried it. You can find more information about theme config in [the  documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/theme-guide/configuration?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/theme-guide#config-fields).